# Goal seek function in python to find scaling factor

Tags: python, scipy-optimize

I am trying to implement a goal-seek function to find a scaling factor for an array. Currently attempting to use `scipy.optimize.fsolve`. I am not sure if this is the right approach. Basically I have an array and I want to find the scaling factor to multiply each value in the array until the sum of the array matches a target value.

```
Target_value = 1169308000

def func(x):
   return sum(array*x) - Target_value

scaling_factor = fsolve(func, 0.1)
```

The above returns 0.1, which was the initial value I gave `fsolve`. I must not be using this function correctly or this isn't what I need. Any guidance here?

Comment: What does `array` look like? Can you provide a sample of that array?

Answer (score 1):

This problem seems trivial? It certainly doesn't call for `fsolve`:

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import default_rng

# synthetic data
rand = default_rng(seed=0)
array = rand.uniform(low=10_000_000, high=90_000_000, size=1_000)

# solution
target_value = 1_169_308_000
scaling_factor = target_value/array.sum()

# test
assert np.isclose(target_value, (array*scaling_factor).sum())
```

Answer (score -1):

I would check out the `scipy.optimize` and utilise the function `fsolve`.

**Here is the modified code**:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

Target_value = 1169308000

array = np.array([...])  # put your array values here

def func(x):
    return np.sum(array * x) - Target_value

scaling_factor = fsolve(func, 0.1)
print(scaling_factor)
```

Comment: How is this different than the code OP shared?